# angular2 ngModel value from ngFor in textarea field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to properly use `ngModel` on `textarea` field whilst its in `ngFor`? Well its showing me the correct name in the `ngModel` however it puts the `ngModel` the rendered html looks like `<textarea>Input name</textarea>` which it shouldn't show like the image below, as I have a `placeholder=""`

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount">
  <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" id="" rows="3" class="search-area-txt" placeholder="Search Product {{inputSearch.name}}"
  [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.name"></textarea>                            
</div>
```

example of the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/FyxwvqsSRhFBUG4CEiKC?p=preview

Comment: Could you provide Plunker link?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FyxwvqsSRhFBUG4CEiKC?p=preview here's an example, I've added my `model=sampleModel` which is being added as a value in the input.